# At hover I want to refresh my page

Tags: html, css, refresh

Here is my code

```
<input type="button"  class="refresh" value="refresh">

<style>

.refresh {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
    border: medium none navy;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    cursor:pointer;  } .refresh:hover{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;}   </style>
```

I want to refresh my page on hover through CSS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need to write a Javascript code

below is jQuery (javascript library) code

```
$('.refresh').hover(function(){

window.location.reload();

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as CSS is for styling, I'm going to say no.....
This would most likely be done with Javascript.  For example:

```
onmouseover="window.location.reload()"
```

Comment: I prefer this solution compared to the jQuery solution, because it is a really simple task where no library is really needed...

Answer (score 0):

just use onmouseover="function(this)" on your link like in below link:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp